Trouble loading CrystalDecisions in C#: FileNotFoundException ReportDocumen
I'm developing a C# application that utilizes Crystal Reports for report generation. I've installed Crystal Reports dependencies via NuGet (e.g., CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine), but I'm encountering issues when running the application.
When attempting to initialize a ReportDocument in my code, I'm getting the following exception:
enter image description here
FileNotFoundException: Unable to load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the specified file.

Here are the steps I've taken:
Installed Crystal Reports Runtime: I have installed the Crystal Reports runtime on my machine to ensure that all required components are available for my application.
Installed NuGet Packages: I have installed the necessary Crystal Reports NuGet packages (e.g., CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine) in my Visual Studio project to reference Crystal Reports functionalities.
Cleaned Solution: I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution in Visual Studio to ensure that all dependencies are properly resolved and included in the build.
enter image description here
enter image description here
